# Could someone explain the behaviour of async-await here?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using the code below I get a return value of result [object Promise]3 . Could you explain me and put some light on what is this [object promise]3 is it an array of 3 promise objects? or something else?

```js
const add = (a,b) => {
    return new Promise((resolve,request) => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            resolve(a+b)
        },2000)
    })
}

const doWork = async ()=> {
    const sum = await add(1, 99)
    const sum2 = await add(sum, 50)
    const sum3 = await add(sum2, 3)
    return sum3
}

doWork().then((result)=>{
    console.log('result', result)
}).catch((e)=>{
    console.log('error', e)
})
```

[outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTBid.png)

Comment: `sum2` is a promise. When you use `+` operator to add `3` to it, it calls the `toString()` on the promise and it returns `[object Promise]`

Comment: You're missing a bunch of `await` eg `const sum = await add(1, 99)`

Comment: It looks like you have edited your question in such a way that the issue you initially reported is no longer reproducible. Are you still waiting for an answer here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sum2 is a promise. When you use + operator to add 3 to it, it calls the toString() on the promise and it returns [object Promise]